# How to catch Parameter and redirect it to other page C# aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I'm doing an enhancement work on a project. This is Original code that parse paramenter string to Summary.aspx on data creation. but then realise when the user created the data there is no notification of "Successfully Submitted" therefore i need to create a semi-static SuccessPage.aspx to show use that they have successfully submitted form. and click the URL to redirect to Summary.aspx

```
String Parameters = "type=1&data1=" + _rguid.ToString() + "&data2=" + _handsetplanvalue.Text.ToString();
Response.Redirect("Summary.aspx?" + Parameters.ToString());
```

New code

```
Response.Redirect("SuccessPage.aspx?" + Parameters.ToString());
```

[image]

The image shows how the semi static page will look like. In the successpage it will check if the type=1 from parameter and if it is 1 the url will`Response.Redirect("Summary.aspx?" + Parameters.ToString());`
if type=2 `Response.Redirect("Summary2.aspx?" + Parameters.ToString());`

My SuccessPage is clean i have no idea how to code it please help

```
  public partial class STSS_stsSuccessPage : BasePage
{
    protected static readonly System.Web.UI.Page page = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Master.strHeader = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("BaseLocale", "lbl_stsSuccessPage_Desc") as string;

            ?????
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a querystring called parameters. Thats a variable name. Your querystring has key/value such as "type", "mobilesale1"..... And not to sound harsh, but you properly need to read some tutorials/beginner guides because it's one of the most basic parts of web.

Comment: Yea sorry im new to aspx haha

Answer (score 0):

```
var type = Request.QueryString["type"];

            if (type == "1")
            {
                var data= Request.QueryString["data1"];
                var data2= Request.QueryString["data2"];

                String Parameters = data1+ data2;

            }
            if (type == "2")
            {
                var data1= Request.QueryString["data1"];
                var data2= Request.QueryString["data2"];
                var data3= Request.QueryString["data3"];
                var data4= Request.QueryString["data4"];

                String Parameters = data1+ data2+ data3+ dat4;
            }
```